# How do I access the location data when app is terminated [carp_background_location]

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

It is a great library. But I am having an issue, I can't understand how do I access the location data when the app is terminated. I can see the data updating in the notification panel but that data is updating from a kotlin file which is inside the package. how do I access the location data in dart file.

Here is the package

[carp_background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location)

This issue is already closed with no answer here

[Github issue](https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues/318#issue-842602350)

Can anyone help me with this